# mat-form-field outline border color

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

It looks like the border color of `mat-form-field` has been updated

- The v15 is black
- The v12 is grey

[image: example]

Is it possible to add an option to change the based color?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The border of `mat-form-field` is created by block `.mdc-notched-outline`. You can set border to this, but it overlaps the old border this may cause an strikethrough label when typing.

Using DevTools, you can see they are using 3 element inside this block: `__leading`, `__notch` and `__trailing`. By change the `border-color` attribute of them:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__leading {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
}
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__notch {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
}
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
}
```

Now `mat-form-field` has darkorange border color. You can also change the `border-radius` to your form:

```
...
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px !important;
}
```

This is **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-form-field-border)**.

---

Update: because the block has no other element, we can shorten by:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline > * {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
}
```

---

Update 2: You can also apply color depend on status of input field by:

- For **INPUT_NOT_TOUCHED**:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline > * {
  border-color: green !important;
}
```

- For **INPUT_FOCUSED**:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline > * {
  border-color: darkorange !important;
}
```

- For **INPUT_ERROR**:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-text-field--invalid .mdc-notched-outline > * {
  border-color: cyan !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem with this solution is that you apply the color on every state of the input:

- INPUT_NOT_TOUCHED: darkorange
- INPUT_FOCUSED: darkorange
- INPUT_ERROR: darkorange

The purpose is to have: 
- INPUT_NOT_TOUCHED: light-grey
- INPUT_FOCUSED: darkorange
- INPUT_ERROR: red

Comment: You can change that by style for special class (of parent or children element). I have updated the example - just use CSS selectors.