# Remove input border from mat paginator

Tags: html, angular, sass, angular-material

I am using a mat-paginator and it looks like this [image]

The only problem is that I want to erase the blue border that appears at the select input, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove the border you should use this.

```
.mdc-notched-outline__trailing,
.mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-notched-outline__leading {
    border: none !important;
}
```

this will delete the border, hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

In Angular Material v15, this ca be achieved as follows:

```
::ng-deep .mdc-notched-outline > * {
  border: none !important;
}
```

This answer is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/75258592/2358409

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box: You can change it with Material themes.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

If you want to play dirty, you can also go at the CSS directly.

```
.mat-mdc-form-field.mat-primary .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mat-mdc-form-field.mat-primary .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mat-mdc-form-field.mat-primary .mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: #fff445;
}
```

Comment: this just changes the color of the focus of the form, but the border still appearing even if set transparent